# How to create UWP setup installer like Windows Build

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

How to create the setup installer for the UWP application. For the desktop application. Please advice

Comment: This is documented by Microsoft, isn't it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps ? Do you need to know something more specific?

Comment: You cant but can create appx package which can be installed on win 10 devices only if dev mode or sideload is on

Answer (score 5):

The .appx package that VS produces for your UWP project is your installer. You can double-click the file, which will launch the built-in installer. In other words, with UWP the installer tech is already built into Windows.

Outside of VS, you can also use the makeappx SDK tool to produce an .appx package for your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Comment: Please can you send the steps in detail to create the UWP desktop setup.

Comment: See steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps, let me know if you run into any problems

Comment: Thanks for you valid information. When i install the appx bundle in the Windows 10 its Asking the certificate for Trusted certificate after selecting the certificate to the appxbundle then able to install the App in the desktop. But client asking why its asking certificate. We need to just install without asking certificate. Please advice

Comment: We will only install packages that are signed with a certificate that is trusted on the computer we install to. This is an important part of our trustworthy deployment promise. Otherwise, how would you know the package comes from a trusted source and is not adware, malware or ransomware? This is easy to do for your client and the right thing to do: they need to obtain a certificate that they deploy to their machines and then you sign your app(s) with that certificate and it will work seamlessly.

Comment: Ok, Let me know If we want to upload in the Windows Store. Can we do directly without a certificate?

Comment: If you submit to the Windows Store it will be signed by Microsoft with the Store certificate which is trusted by default on all Windows devices.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Then the same build will be used to mobile also? Please advice

Comment: Yes. Of course you need to make sure your package contains binaries that work on ARM in order to support Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: Can you send the binaries name that work in both Windows 10 desktop & Windows mobile

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The binaries in the package are your app binaries, I don't know their names. What i am saying is that if your app is called FOO.EXE the package bundle you upload to the Store should contain x86, x64 and ARM versions of FOO.EXE in order to support all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me check and tel you if i have any doubt

Comment: Thank u So much. We upload in the Windows Store and able to install in all mobile and Windows Desktop